# Mongo-Connector, MongoDB OPLOG and ElasticSearch configuration

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I have a simple question that only an expert can answer. Is this configuration possible?

- host1 — runs mongo-connector
- host2 — runs ElasicSearch
- host3 — runs MongoDB (replicamode)

The million dollar question is: Can I use mongo-connector to propagate changes that occur in MongoDb to ElasticSearch? The underlying issue is the MongoDB opLog file. Mongo-Connector uses that file to probagate crud actions to ElasticSearch. How can this be made to work in this type of configuration?

Answer (score 0):

answering my own question after doing a simple test involving two macbooks.

```
I did the following to test.
```

1. ran a mongo-connector on a macBook.
2. configured the mongo-connector to connect to a MongoDB running on a different Macbook .. and to connect to an ElasticSearch engine running on a different macBook.
3. Note that the mongoDB and the Elastic Search Engine were on the same box in this configuration.

```
what I observed:
Mongo-connector was able to monitor the mongodb running remotely and was able to
 update Elastic search with all changes that hit the MongoDB. I started with 
an empty ElasticSearch. Mongo-Connector was able to load all historical data 
and then proceeded to load any real-time inserts/updates and deletes on 
Mongodb into Elastic Search.
---- SO IT WORKS ----
The trick is this: Use REAL IP ADDRESSES IN YOUR CONFIGURATION FILES.
```